# SearchView query hint before clicking it

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a search view and I have a query hint attribute. However the hint appears only after clicking on the search view. Is there a way to make it appear before it has been clicked?

```
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:queryHint="Search" />
```

[image]

[image]

I have seen another SO question with a similar query, but it wasn't solved. That's why I am asking again.

Comment: because it is in "iconified" state

Comment: Here my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681500/android-4-3-not-focus-searchview-not-show-hint?noredirect=1#comment80355499_46681500

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use this XML:

```
android:queryHint="hint"
app:queryHint="hint"
app:defaultQueryHint="hint"
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"  // this line
app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

app used for {android.support.v7.widget.SearchView}

Comment: this is the correct answer! Not the selected one... Thank you!

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer. 
`android:iconifiedByDefault="false"`

Comment: Exactly this one ++++

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

and try this to hide focus (Keyboard)

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                search.clearFocus();
            }
    }, 300);
```

Comment: Just checked, and found an attribute in xml iconifiedByDefault. I set that to false and it worked. Thanks. :)

Comment: searchView.setIconified(false); did work for me. Thanks :)

Comment: searchView.setIconified(false); - is focus searchView and as result show hint .But I need to show hint when searchView is not in focus. How I can do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can just add `android:iconifiedByDefault="false"` it just displays the query hint string by default

Answer (score 5):

This is a complete XML, You can try this.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/PlayerSearchView"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:paddingStart="-4dp"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_person_search"
                app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close"
                app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Add this in style

```
<style name="PlayerSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <item name="queryHint">@string/search_player</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_10ssp</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="android:queryHint">@color/colorBlack</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

make setIconified(false)-that works for me
that works,but when it is unclicked,again hint disappears

Answer (score 2):

use those attributes

```
<SearchView
.
.
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
          searchView.clearFocus();
    }
}, 300);
```

Also, don't forget to add these to manifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
  searchView.setQueryHint("Search for countries…");
  searchView.setIconified(false);

  menu.add("Search")
      .setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_search)
      .setActionView(searchView)
      .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score -4):

In xml, You can use this
android:queryHint="Search"

Comment: Please add more information to your answer (a complete example , a valuable link).