# Android 4.3: Not focus searchView not show hint

Tags: android, searchview

Android Studio 2.3.3, Android 4.3.

In my fragment I has **searchView** component (not in ToolBar). Here my snippet.

fragment_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_view_bg"
        app:defaultQueryHint="@string/settings"
        app:searchHintIcon="@null" />   

</LinearLayout>
```

In my fragment:

```
  private void init(View view) {
        searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchCatalogSuggestionsAdapter(getActivity()));
        ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(view.findViewById(R.id.searchView), ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

    }
```

Here result when **searchView** has focus:

[image: Has focus]

And here result when **searchView** has no focus:
[image: No focus]

As you can see the hint show only when **searchView** is on focus.
But I need also to show hint when **searchView** is not in focus. I want hint to be always visible.

P.S. If use method `searchView.setIconified(false)` then **searchView** auto get focus. But I need to get focus only when user click on **searchView**.

Comment: Try after adding this line - searchView.setSelected(true);

Comment: Not help. Same result. No hint on not focus state.

Comment: Try to request focus on the wrapped `EditText`: `EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);` and then `editText.post(() -> editText.requestFocus())`;

Comment: `final EditText editText = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        editText.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                editText.requestFocus();
            }
        });`   not help. same result

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for Android 4.3+:

1. I use microphone icon , disable click on it and replace it by custom icon(glass)
2. Hide keyboard after 300 msec (because `onActionViewExpanded()` show soft keyboard)

As result I has:

1. Show hint when **searchView** is not focus
2. Show icon on the right side when **searchView** is on focus and when **searchView** is NOT in focus

Here my snippet:

Java code:

```
 ImageView voiceButtonIcon = view.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_voice_btn);
        voiceButtonIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_black);
        voiceButtonIcon.setEnabled(false);

        // Workaround! Show hint when searchView has no focus
        searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                searchView.clearFocus();
            }
        }, 300);
```

layout xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_view_bg"
        android:theme="@style/SearchViewTheme"
        app:defaultQueryHint="@string/settings"
        app:searchHintIcon="@null" />
```

As result:
**searchView** has NO focus:

[image: No_focus]

and **searchView** HAS in focus:

[image: Has_focus]

So hint show always!