# How to send image position to another activity in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gridview

I'm trying to make a list of images with a gridview which when the user selects one of the images will display the selected image in fullscreen. What I want to ask is how to know the position of the selected image and notify the image's position to the intent so that it can be displayed in fullscreen?

```
package com.example.bpskotayogyakarta.ui.infografis;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.bpskotayogyakarta.R;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public class InfografisFragment extends Fragment {

    private InfografisViewModel infografisViewModel;
    private List<Spacecraft> spacecraftList;

    private GridViewAdapter adapter;
    private GridView gridView;
    ProgressBar myProgressBar;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        infografisViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InfografisViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_infografis, container, false);

        final ProgressBar myProgressBar= root.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        MyAPIService myAPIService = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(MyAPIService.class);
        gridView = root.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        Call<List<Spacecraft>> call = myAPIService.getSpacecrafts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Spacecraft>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Spacecraft>> call, Response<List<Spacecraft>> response) {
                myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                spacecraftList = response.body();
                adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getContext(), spacecraftList);
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Spacecraft>> call, Throwable throwable) {
                myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    class Spacecraft {
        /*
        INSTANCE FIELDS
         */
        @SerializedName("id_info")
        private int id_info;

        @SerializedName("gambar_info")
        private String gambar_info;

        public Spacecraft(int id_info, String gambar_info) {
            this.id_info = id_info;
            this.gambar_info = gambar_info;
        }

        /*
         *GETTERS AND SETTERS
         */
        public int getId() {
            return id_info;
        }
        public void setId(int id_info) {
            this.id_info = id_info;
        }

        public String getImageURL() {
            return gambar_info;
        }
    }

    interface MyAPIService {

        @GET("connection_image_bps.php")
        Call<List<Spacecraft>> getSpacecrafts();
    }

    static class RetrofitClientInstance {

        private static Retrofit retrofit;
        private static final String BASE_URL = "https://bpskotayogyakarta.000webhostapp.com/";

        public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }
    }

    class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;
        private Context context;

        public GridViewAdapter(Context context,List<Spacecraft> spacecrafts){
            this.context = context;
            this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return spacecrafts.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return spacecrafts.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if(view==null)
            {
                view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_gambar_info,viewGroup,false);
            }

            ImageView spacecraftImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            spacecraftImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            final Spacecraft thisSpacecraft= spacecrafts.get(position);

            if(thisSpacecraft.getImageURL() != null && thisSpacecraft.getImageURL().length()>0)
            {
                Picasso.get().load(thisSpacecraft.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(spacecraftImageView);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Empty Image URL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.placeholder).into(spacecraftImageView);
            }

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                private int id_temp = thisSpacecraft.getId();

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullscreenInfo.class);
                    intent.putExtra("image", String.valueOf(thisSpacecraft)); // put image data in Intent
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

And below is the code that I intend to send to

```
package com.example.bpskotayogyakarta.ui.infografis;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.bpskotayogyakarta.R;

public class FullscreenInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView selectedImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_info);
        selectedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_view_image); // init a ImageView
        Intent intent = getIntent(); // get Intent which we set from Previous Activity
        selectedImage.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra("image", 0)); // get image from Intent and set it in ImageView
    }
}
```

So what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Instead of sending the position of the image, you can send the path of the selected image (clicked image) to activity.

Comment: @AtishAgrawal Hmm can you specifically explain your answer?

Comment: Try Sandeep's Answer once. His approach is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onItemClickListener for that

```
   // Implement On Item click listener
gridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       Spacecraft spaceCraft = (Spacecraft)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity,FullscreenInfo.class);
       intent.putExtra("image_url",spaceCraft.getImageURL());
       startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

and inside your fullscreenInfo you can set your image like this

```
public class FullscreenInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView selectedImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_info);
    selectedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_view_image); // init a ImageView
     String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");
      //you can use this image url to load image in your imageview by Using any library like picasso or Glide
}
```

}

Comment: hello can you help me out here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532667/particular-titlefetched-from-api-using-searchview