# Android Kotlin ImageView on top of each other, one is hidden with android:visibility="gone" when both switch visibility second image is always blank?

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

Here's my layout

```
          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/my_img1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/my_img2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Both ImageView were loaded with glide

```
Glide.with(MyImg1).load(Img1Url).into(MyImg1)
Glide.with(MyImg2).load(Img2Url).into(MyImg2)
```

When user click a button I just switch their visibility

```
    if (MyImg1.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        MyImg1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        MyImg2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    else {
        MyImg1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        MyImg2.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
```

Now the problem is MyImg2 will always be blank no matter how many times the switch button was click. If I change android:visibility="gone" from my_img2 and put it to my_img1 then MyImg2 will show and this means image loading is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `View.INVISIBLE` try with `View.GONE`

```
if (MyImg1.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        MyImg1.visibility = View.GONE
        MyImg2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    else {
        MyImg1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        MyImg2.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```

Comment: Glad! It helped you. Happy Coding.

Comment: hiii @VirRajpurohit..can you help me out here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532667/particular-titlefetched-from-api-using-searchview

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RelativeLayout as the parent for both of them then add 
     android:layoutparentBelow = "@+id/my_img_1"
In your second imageview layout file