# Background Image gone compressed when keyboard is open

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I am making signup page using this image background.

**Background image**
[image]

It Look like: **Signup page**

[image]
But when I focus on EditText and when keyboard is opened, the background image is compressed. How can I resolve this.

After Compressed :
[image]

Here XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/log_sign_bg">

    </RelativeLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="260dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                android:hint="Re-enter Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:text="Register"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="Already a member?"
                android:textColor="#A6A6A6"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="#EF3646"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I tried to many ways but i think i have to separate the bakgrounf image and the logo one may be fix it.

Comment: What it looks like when keyboard open? And also add your layout xml

Comment: @HemantCTD, Your layout is not correct. *ScrollView can not host multiple direct child*

Comment: Editetxt Hint issue resolved or not? Did you checked my updated answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your xml file is not correct ScrollView can not contain multiple child, i have resolved your problem.So Please follow my answer.

if you want to scroll only view not top image then use this one

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/signup_bg"
        >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"

            android:textSize="22dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

            android:hint="Re-enter Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"

            android:textSize="22dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
            android:background="#EF3646"
            android:text="Register"

            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Already a member?"
            android:textColor="#A6A6A6"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#EF3646"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: remove this line from manifest file
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan|adjustResize"

Comment: look at relative layout bro image i am using for full screen but you take only 150

Comment: issue with scroll view for contraint layout views like edittext i want to scroll them

Comment: InsaneCat Please check my comment carefully, use multiple child not single constraint layout

Comment: i got it i removed relative layout from you code and added background to constraint layout and added margin top in first edittext of 260dp

Comment: you can without remove the relative layout, check my new answer

Comment: i told you that i have full screen bacground image look at images in my question

Comment: if you want to full screen then in relative layout add app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
and  android:layout_height="0dp"

Comment: there is no need of relative layout

Comment: another issue is textview not showing full text can you solve it

Comment: @HemantCTD Please add a View with 40 dp height on bottom of textView2 or you can give   android:paddingBottom="40dp" in constraint_inner for showing your bottom textview when keyboard open and scrolling full view.

Answer (score 2):

Into your AndroidManifest.xml file add below line to your activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

Like below snippet register in

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan|adjustResize" />
```

You mentioned issue in comment section so solution is here,
Run time Set Edittext  Hint:

```
EditText etName;
etName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
etName.setHint("Your Hint");
```

Comment: it fixed my resize issue but edittext is hiding by keyboard how to scroll up

Comment: Aaah Great!! you need to scroll itwhen keyboard is open.! @HemantCTD

Comment: @InsaneCat..can you help me out here--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532667/particular-titlefetched-from-api-using-searchview

Comment: @Wini Ok let me check it!!

Comment: @InsaneCat..did you check??I haven't found any solution of my problem...nobody has given proper solution...

Comment: you want to scroll full view or only text field ?

Comment: only textfield @Avinash

Comment: check my first layout, it may helps you.